# Vuejs nested v-for and <tr> tag issue

Tags: html, vue.js, html-table, binding, v-for

When I try nesting a  inside a  with a v-for binding on each, vue complains that the properties are undefined. What's the problem?

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in items">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <tr v-for="child in item.children">
        <td>{{ child.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/78s3qnz5/

Comment: You are nesting `tr` inside `tr`. Is that what you really mean? Try replace the inner `tr` to `td`.

Comment: @Psidom yes, this is intentional. The markup snippet is from a larger table that has "accordion" rows (ie clicking on a row expands 1-n child rows). This is working fine for a nested <tr> and a single v-for on the inner <tr>, but is causing errors when both parent and child <tr> tags have the v-for binding applied.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use template tags in case you want to use rows.

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <template v-for="item in items">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="child in item.children">
        <td>{{ child.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes. This. This is exactly what I was looking for. You just made my day.

Answer (score -1):

Issue is because of `<tr>` tag nested inside another `<tr>` tag, which causes invalid markup and `Vue` fails to render it. Indeed., error message is not clear.

Solution is to fix rendered markup, by replacing nested `<tr>` with `<td>`.

Working example:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aBiscuit/78s3qnz5/4/)